# How can I pass a non-static variable to an async block?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

According to the docs on [task::spawn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) (note I'm using [tokio::spawn](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.4.0/tokio/fn.spawn.html) which seems similar but lacks the description)

> The `'static` constraint means that the closure and its return value must have a lifetime of the whole program execution. The reason for this is that threads can detach and outlive the lifetime they have been created in. Indeed if the thread, and by extension its return value, can outlive their caller, we need to make sure that they will be valid afterwards, and since we can't know when it will return we need to have them valid as long as possible, that is until the end of the program, hence the `'static` lifetime.

I'm trying to pass a `Url` into a thread, like this,

```
do_update(confg.to_feed_url()).await;
```

Where I do this in `do_update`,

```
  async fn do_update(url: Url) {
    let task = task::spawn(async {
      let duration = Duration::from_millis(5_000);
      let mut stream = time::interval(duration);
      stream.tick().await;
      loop {
        feeds::MyFeed::from_url(url.clone(), true);
```

This doesn't work and generates these errors,

> error[E0373]: async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `url`, which is owned by the current function

I've read the docs, but this doesn't much make sense to me because I'm cloning in the block. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: *The 'static constraint means that the closure and its return value must have a lifetime of the whole program execution.* - This is slightly misleading. The closure must either _own_ the values it uses (in which case it can prolong their lifetimes arbitrarily) or, if it refers to non-owned values, those must be valid until the end of the program. Non-static data can be made owned just by moving it to the closure. If you need to keep referring to the data, you can wrap it in an `Arc` and move its clone into the closure.

Comment: See [this excellent guide](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program) for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, if you don't need the URL elsewhere, you can write `async move` for your block instead of `async`, which will move the URL (and anything else the block captures, which it looks like is nothing) into the block.

If you do need it elsewhere, then you can clone the `url` variable outside of the block and then do the same thing (`async move`) to move just that particular variable into the block and not `url` itself.  The `clone` call will probably not be necessary in such a case.

This occurs because `url` lives outside the block and calling `url.clone` borrows it (probably immutably, but it depends on the implementation).  Since its scope is this function and not the life of the program, it won't live for the `'static` lifetime and hence you need to move it into the block instead of borrowing.

Comment: Worked wonderfully, thanks. I was trying to create a `move || async {}` didn't know the syntax for `async move {}`